# How to return one value per group in SQL

Tags: sql

Example I have loan accounts of multiple customers. I just need to extract a list where only last instalment appears.

```
Cust|Account|Instalment No|Amount|X|Y|Z|.....

ABC |CHK-0001234|1|100

ABC |CHK-0001234|2|100

ABC |CHK-0001234|3|100

ABC |CHK-0001234|4|100

DEF |CHK-0001235|1|150

DEF |CHK-0001235|2|150

DEF |CHK-0001235|3|150

DEF |CHK-0001235|4|150

DEF |CHK-0001235|5|150

DEF |CHK-0001235|6|150
```

OUTPUT -

```
ABC |CHK-0001234|4|100

DEF |CHK-0001235|6|150
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Can you show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Try this select colums_name from tblname group by colums_name

Comment: I am using SQL server. I cannot share the whole query here. But with example above can you assist me on how to get the OUTPUT as mentioned above.

Comment: [This is one of the most asked question on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+get+last+row+of+each+group+site:stackoverflow.com). Why didn't any of those answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would dive into groupings for SQL deeper since I notice you don't understand the functionality. Check this out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Now, to get the result you specify you need:

```
SELECT Cust, Account, MAX(Instalment No), Amount FROM table_name
GROUP BY Cust, Account, Amount
```

I added the MAX(Instalment No) because apparently you don't want it grouped on that field but you do want to include it in the results?

Please be more clear in your questions next time.
Check this out: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)